# Solving a system of linear equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let $p$ be a particular solution to:

$$Ax = b$$

Let $g$ be the general solution to the above equation.

Let $h$ be the general solution to the equation:

$$Ax = 0$$

Then

$$g = p + h$$

Could someone please explain why the above fact is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: if $p$ and $q$ are solutions of $Ax=b$, then $p-q$ is a solution of....

Answer (score 0):

Go step by step in your equations given. If you know that p is a solution of Ax=b and g is a general solution to that, follow from there. You know h is the solution to Ax=0, so g must equal both p plus h.